# Razor not recognizing Model and other syntax keywords

Tags: asp.net-core, razor, asp.net-core-mvc

We have a codebase where our home grown CRM is an older .Net Framework web app that has a mix of web forms and mvc razor pages.  We're working on converting it to .Net 5 and to this point have converted all of our infrastructure projects (business layer, data layer, etc.) to .NetStandard 2.  Since we did this, intellisense no longer works in razor pages for models and htmlhelpers.  It's doing this for all of the developers who work on this.  It does this in VS 2019 and 2022.  It was working fine before we started this upgrade, so I'm not sure what would cause this.  The image below shows what it's doing.

[image]

Updated with the csproj file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" ToolsVersion="Current">
  <Import Project="..\packages\EntityFramework.6.4.4\build\EntityFramework.props" Condition="Exists('..\packages\EntityFramework.6.4.4\build\EntityFramework.props')" />
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props')" />
  <Import Project="..\packages\Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SNI.5.0.1\build\net46\Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SNI.targets" Condition="Exists('..\packages\Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SNI.5.0.1\build\net46\Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SNI.targets')" />
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
    <ProductVersion>9.0.30729</ProductVersion>
    <SchemaVersion>2.0</SchemaVersion>
    <ProjectGuid>{B1B23E2B-2833-40D4-9E95-1515BAC57C63}</ProjectGuid>
    <ProjectTypeGuids>{349c5851-65df-11da-9384-00065b846f21};{fae04ec0-301f-11d3-bf4b-00c04f79efbc}</ProjectTypeGuids>
    <OutputType>Library</OutputType>
    <AppDesignerFolder>Properties</AppDesignerFolder>
    <RootNamespace>CMPWare</RootNamespace>
    <AssemblyName>CMPWare</AssemblyName>
    <SccProjectName>
    </SccProjectName>
    <SccLocalPath>
    </SccLocalPath>
    <SccAuxPath>
    </SccAuxPath>
    <SccProvider>
    </SccProvider>
    <FileUpgradeFlags>
    </FileUpgradeFlags>
    <UpgradeBackupLocation>
    </UpgradeBackupLocation>
    <OldToolsVersion>2.0</OldToolsVersion>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.7.2</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    <TargetFrameworkProfile />
    <UseIISExpress>true</UseIISExpress>
    <IISExpressSSLPort>44336</IISExpressSSLPort>
    <IISExpressAnonymousAuthentication>
    </IISExpressAnonymousAuthentication>
    <IISExpressWindowsAuthentication>
    </IISExpressWindowsAuthentication>
    <IISExpressUseClassicPipelineMode>
    </IISExpressUseClassicPipelineMode>
    <UseGlobalApplicationHostFile />
    <NuGetPackageImportStamp>
    </NuGetPackageImportStamp>
    <Use64BitIISExpress />
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <Optimize>false</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
    <TreatWarningsAsErrors>true</TreatWarningsAsErrors>
    <Prefer32Bit>false</Prefer32Bit>
    <LangVersion>7.0</LangVersion>
    <PlatformTarget>AnyCPU</PlatformTarget>
    <CodeAnalysisRuleSet>MinimumRecommendedRules.ruleset</CodeAnalysisRuleSet>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
    <TreatWarningsAsErrors>true</TreatWarningsAsErrors>
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <Prefer32Bit>false</Prefer32Bit>
    <LangVersion>7.0</LangVersion>
    <CodeAnalysisRuleSet>MinimumRecommendedRules.ruleset</CodeAnalysisRuleSet>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <VisualStudioVersion Condition="'$(VisualStudioVersion)' == ''">17.0</VisualStudioVersion>
    <VSToolsPath Condition="'$(VSToolsPath)' == ''">$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)</VSToolsPath>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Dev|AnyCPU'">
    <OutputPath>bin\</OutputPath>
    <LangVersion>7.0</LangVersion>
    <CodeAnalysisRuleSet>MinimumRecommendedRules.ruleset</CodeAnalysisRuleSet>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Live|AnyCPU'">
    <OutputPath>bin\</OutputPath>
    <LangVersion>7.0</LangVersion>
    <CodeAnalysisRuleSet>MinimumRecommendedRules.ruleset</CodeAnalysisRuleSet>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildBinPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
  <Import Project="$(VSToolsPath)\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" Condition="'$(VSToolsPath)' != ''" />
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v17.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" Condition="false" />
  <!-- To modify your build process, add your task inside one of the targets below and uncomment it. 
       Other similar extension points exist, see Microsoft.Common.targets.
  <Target Name="BeforeBuild">
  </Target>
  <Target Name="AfterBuild">
  </Target>
  -->
  <ProjectExtensions>
    <VisualStudio>
      <FlavorProperties GUID="{349c5851-65df-11da-9384-00065b846f21}">
        <WebProjectProperties>
          <UseIIS>True</UseIIS>
          <AutoAssignPort>True</AutoAssignPort>
          <DevelopmentServerPort>49771</DevelopmentServerPort>
          <DevelopmentServerVPath>/</DevelopmentServerVPath>
          <IISUrl>https://localhost:44301/</IISUrl>
          <NTLMAuthentication>False</NTLMAuthentication>
          <UseCustomServer>False</UseCustomServer>
          <CustomServerUrl>
          </CustomServerUrl>
          <SaveServerSettingsInUserFile>False</SaveServerSettingsInUserFile>
        </WebProjectProperties>
      </FlavorProperties>
    </VisualStudio>
  </ProjectExtensions>
  <Target Name="EnsureNuGetPackageBuildImports" BeforeTargets="PrepareForBuild">
    <PropertyGroup>
      <ErrorText>This project references NuGet package(s) that are missing on this computer. Use NuGet Package Restore to download them.  For more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=322105. The missing file is {0}.</ErrorText>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <Error Condition="!Exists('..\packages\EntityFramework.6.4.4\build\EntityFramework.props')" Text="$([System.String]::Format('$(ErrorText)', '..\packages\EntityFramework.6.4.4\build\EntityFramework.props'))" />
    <Error Condition="!Exists('..\packages\EntityFramework.6.4.4\build\EntityFramework.targets')" Text="$([System.String]::Format('$(ErrorText)', '..\packages\EntityFramework.6.4.4\build\EntityFramework.targets'))" />
    <Error Condition="!Exists('..\packages\Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SNI.5.0.1\build\net46\Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SNI.targets')" Text="$([System.String]::Format('$(ErrorText)', '..\packages\Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SNI.5.0.1\build\net46\Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SNI.targets'))" />
    <Error Condition="!Exists('..\packages\NETStandard.Library.2.0.3\build\netstandard2.0\NETStandard.Library.targets')" Text="$([System.String]::Format('$(ErrorText)', '..\packages\NETStandard.Library.2.0.3\build\netstandard2.0\NETStandard.Library.targets'))" />
  </Target>
  <Import Project="..\packages\NETStandard.Library.2.0.3\build\netstandard2.0\NETStandard.Library.targets" Condition="Exists('..\packages\NETStandard.Library.2.0.3\build\netstandard2.0\NETStandard.Library.targets')" />
</Project>
```

Comment: Post your `csproj` file. The Razor editor in VS needs _very specific_ MSBuild project-properties and services set in order to work, which is why you can't use the Razor editor in a non-web-project. Also, there's 3 different versions of the Razor editor too, which support slightly different syntax.

Comment: The csproj file is huge and goes over the character limit.  Is there a specific section of it that you want to look at?

Comment: Remove all of the `<ItemGroup>` elements (and their children) - I'm only interested in `<PropropertyGroup>` elements and other elements.

Comment: But Webform is not supported by the .net 5 now. If you want to move, one possible way is re-design the whole application instead of modify the old project.

Comment: I know that.  That's not the problem.  With this particular project, we have a second version in .net 5 where we're migrating pages from the old one to the new one.